# Elements keep going stale using PageFactory

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, pageobjects

I have a list of objects i want to confirm some attributes on, the issue is that they reload on the page around once a second.

Whenever I try to refer to any of the elements in the list i get a stale element exception.
I tried refreshing the elements just before checking but i still get the exception.

Is it possible to cache the elements when i initialize them?

This is how i get the elements:

```
            [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = @"//*[@id='Log']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]")] 
            public IList<IWebElement> logs;
```

Comment: If elements are reloading on a page that fast you do not want to store them in a list. I would scrap that idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of CacheLookup, try once

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = @"//*[@id='Log']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]")][CacheLookup]
public IList<IWebElement> logs;
```

Comment: They still become stale sadly